# Google API unauthenticated error

Tags: rest, google-api, youtube-api

I am simply trying to cURL the google api rest resource:

```
curl -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=Miniac&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

the error I'm seeing is:

```
"code": 403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use
```

This is usually an issue because the youtube API isn't enabled on the project where your API key lives, but in my case it is. What else am I missing?

Comment: That only means you need to be authenticated to continue with your requests. You can refer to the [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to see how it's done using OAuth2. There are couple of [Youtube Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php) also to serve as your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to put quotations around the URL.